# Workflow PostGIS-table for OSM-mapping

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I use OSM-data for the development of an population disaggregation algorithm. In order to improve the results I want to add missing attributes to some of the buildings with an OSM-editor. I am identifying these buildings in PostGIS. 
As I want to map the features directly in OpenStreetMap, I am currently looking for an efficient procedure to have an OSM-file with the buildings (from PostGIS-table), which I can then load into JOSM for mapping.

I read some other posts discussing the export of PostGIS-tables with Osmosis. ([Using osmosis to convert POSTGIS Table to .OSM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296532/using-osmosis-to-convert-postgis-table-to-osm))

I however have the doubt and fear that some OSM-information will be lost and accordingly when the updates are pushed to OSM the OSM-dataset will be harmed. Are there any best practice workflows or recommendations for accomplishing this tasks?

Comment: Sounds like an [Import](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import). Please read the [import guidelines](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Guidelines). Or in short: Don't do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I don't want to do an automatic import. The idea is to load only the specific buildings into JOSM and then map them manually.